# Ad items added to my Google searches on top after one second

Tags: google-chrome, virus

If I Google "superuser" I see this for about one second:

[image]

... Followed by this (couple ad items added on top):

[image]

How to I get rid of this abomination? In Chrome settings there's no other search engine specified than Google. I have Malwarebytes free running. Only occurs with Chrome.

Comment: Check for Chrome extensions.

Comment: I checked. Nothing new there, and no extension which could do that.

Comment: Google generates income from its search engine.  Use a different search engine.

Comment: I don't get the same results. Does this happen when using Chrome in Incognito Mode?

Comment: @harrymc: good question, no it doesn't actually! Does that suggest something to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that this does not happen when using Chrome in Incognito Mode is a big hint.

In Incognito Mode extensions are disabled. Since Chrome does not control how
these extensions handle your personal data when you search the Internet,
the solution is to disable them all by default.

This means that some extension is injecting commercial results into your normal
Google results. In other words, Chrome, and perhaps your computer, are infected.

I suggest to :

- Ensure that your Home URL is still the right one and your search URL is really Google
- Verify your extensions in the hamburger menu and choose More tools > Extensions
- Run deep scans using several well-known anti-virus products.

For more information see
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: I think you may have come to the conclusion about malware based on an incorrect premise.  Incognito mode doesn't disable extensions.  The main thing it does is not save your browsing history, cookies and site data, or information entered in forms.  Extensions generally aren't affected.  See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: @fixer1234: Extensions need to be specifically enabled to run in Incognito Mode, which isn't covered by your link. A google search found many articles, here is one : [How to enable Chrome extensions in Incognito mode](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-enable-chrome-extensions-in-incognito/|).

Comment: The link in your comment goes to an "OOPS".  I'm not a regular Chrome user.  I just checked Chromium, and see that there's a checkbox for each extension in the add-ons tab to allow use in incognito mode.  However, my past use of Google has included sponsored listings.  Might there be an alternate explanation that Google recognizes incognito mode and doesn't stick in ads?

Comment: @fixer1234: Sorry about my bad link. I use Google quite a lot in Chrome and other browsers and never encountered such abnormal behavior. Neither have you, I'm sure. It must be an extension, no other reasonable explanation occurs to me.

Comment: @fixer1234: Regarding sponsored listings, this is [Google AdSense](https://www.google.com/adsense/start/), but these are clearly indicated as such and separated from the main search results.